# Cannot unset foreign key value using dropDownList in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, sql-update, yii2

I have a Yii2 form view with the following code.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'field1')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($fieldList, 'id', 'label'), ['prompt' => '']) ?>
```

`field1` above is actually a VARCHAR, NULLable foreign key in a MySQL table. If I unset my selection, choose the blank option and save, I get a foreign key integrity error.

Basically, Yii2 is trying to update the row to '' instead of NULL. How can I fix the above situation?

I also tried `array_merge` instead of `['prompt' => '']` to add a blank field with a NULL value, still no joy.

EDIT:
I ended up checking for blank in the controller, but ideally I should not have to do this. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
$loaded = $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());

if ($model->field1 == '')
    $model->field1 = null;

if ($loaded && $model->save()) {
}
```

Comment: show integrity error. i mean error message.

Comment: To insert Null you can use -  new DbExpression('Null').

Comment: You also can move this IF to Model::beforeSave() method.

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('db'.'tableName', CONSTRAINT 'fk_field1' FOREIGN KEY ('field1') REFERENCES 'table2Name' ('pk_field') ON UPDATE CASCADE)
The SQL being executed was: UPDATE 'tableName' SET 'field1'='' WHERE 'id'='4'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to add this to your Model rules?:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
      ....
      [['field1'], 'default'], // set "field1" as null if they are empty
    ];
}
```

Your constraint error also looks like that in your related table the field1 couldn't be set to null.

Comment: ups this was from yii1 and not yii2 fixed the code.